# Inserting a logo below date in Rmarkdown YAML

Tags: r

I am using the following template in RMarkdown to create a PDF. Is there a way in which the following logo can go below the date instead of above the title?

```
---
title: Adding a Logo to LaTeX Title
author: Michael Harper
date: December 7th, 2018
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{logo.jpg}\LARGE\\}
  - \posttitle{\end{center}}
---
```

This YAML generates a cover page which looks like the image below. I would like the logo to appear below the date

[image: e]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\predate` and `\postdate` commands for this instead of `\pretitle` and `\posttitle`. See more details in the [documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titling/titling.pdf) or check this example:

```
---
title: Adding a Logo to LaTeX Title
author: Michael Harper
date: December 7th, 2018
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \predate{\begin{center}\large}
  - \postdate{\\
      \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{logo.png}\end{center}}
---
```

[image: logo below date]