# Inserting image below date using Rmarkdown YAML

Tags: r, rmarkdown

I am creating a report in Rmarkdown that is knitted into a PDF. I want to include two images on the first page: a logo above the title, and then a nice image below the date. The problem is that the addition of the second image using \postdate seems to confuse the program. It knits perfectly with the top logo when I only include the \posttitle bit of code, but when I add the \postdate bit it fails to knit with the following error code:

"I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log EOS_report_2324.log.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}."

I used the formatting in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554172/inserting-a-logo-below-date-in-rmarkdown-yaml) to try and get the second image to show up with no luck.

```
---
title: "Report 2324"
subtitle: | 
  | Placeholder
  | Placeholder
author: 
-   Person 1, Person 2, Person 3, Person 4, Person 5,
-   Person 6, & Person 7
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B %Y')`"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
    \includegraphics[width=2in, height=2in]{`r paste("Z:/logo.png",sep="")`}\LARGE\\}
- \postdate{\end{center}}
    \includegraphics[width=2in,height=4in]{`r paste("Z:/image2.png",sep="")`}}
output:
  pdf_document:
      fig_caption: true
      toc: true
      extra_dependencies: ["float"]
include-before:
- '`\newpage{}`{=latex}'
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---
```

Any ideas? I've got tinytex and am using pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex).

Comment: Without test the code,  lack a `}` in  `\pretitle{\begin{center}`. Moreover, this is OK have   two `\end{center}` but only one `\begin{center}`?  There are two center environments in the latex output or only one and a half?